# Laravel Query Relationship on One Model Instance

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am aware that I can use `count()` to query for Eloquent relationships in Laravel, like so:

```
if(count($question->answers()))
```

Where `answers()` is a `hasMany` relationship:

```
 public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Answer', 'question_id');
    }
```

My question is, how do I do this when `$question` is not an entire collection but one Model instance?

```
$question = Question::where('id',$key)->first();
```

How do I query the above question, and only that question, for a potential relationship using `count()`?

I always am getting a `count()` of greater than zero, even when the selected question has no associated answers, which means my if block always runs and returns unwarranted `null` values:

```
if(count($question->answers()))
   {
   //returns nulls
   }
```

Comment: Use `count($question->answers)` or `count($question->answers()->get());`; I don't think `count()` is valid on a `QueryBuilder` instance, which is what `$question->answers()` would be.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you!

Comment: @TimLewis If you want to create an answer I can accept it!

Comment: There is an other way eager load answers `$question = Question::with('answers')->where('id',$key)->first();` and then use `count` as you did `if(count($question->answers()))...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since calling `$question->answers()` is returning a `QueryBuilder` instance, calling `count()` on that will most likely always return `1`. If you access `$question->answers` (as a `property` and not a `method`), or use the full logic `$question->answers()->get();` it should properly return a `Collection`, which `count()` will function correctly on:

```
$question = Question::where('id',$key)->first();

if(count($question->answers) > 0){
  // Do something
}

// OR

if(count($question->answers()->get()) > 0){ 
  ... 
}
```

As suggested by @maraboc, you could also eager load your `$question` with `answers` using a `->with()` clause:

```
$question = Question::with(["answers"])->where('id',$key)->first();
```

But even in this case, `$question->answers()` would still be returning a `QueryBuilder` instance, so access it as a `property` for `count()` to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed `count($question->answers())` has no meaning because `$question->answers()` is a Relation instance, you can call dynamic query method on that but if you want to count elements you need a collection, i.e `$question->answers`.

So you have two choice:

1. count the collection: `count($question->answers)`
2. ask the database to do the count: `$question->answers()->count()`

Parentheses matters